# how to access field name in mongoose $aggregate->$lookup-> pipeline->$match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I have below code.

```
Users.aggregate([{
     $lookup: {
          from: "payments",
          // localField:"_id",
          // foreignField:"restaurant_id",
          let: {
               id: "$_id"
          },
          pipeline: [
               {
                    $match: {
                         status: "Active", // If I add only this line it returns the result ->
                         restaurant_id:"$id" //or "$_id"  ->but after adding this line it return empty array
                         //if I change $id to static value of id result comes 
                    },
               }
          ],
          as: "subscription"
     }
}])
```

I am not able to use field name in `$match`. If I am writing static id it is working fine but I need to use dynamic `_id`. Please suggest how can i use field name in `$match`. I have used many things like `$and` `$expr` but nothing worked.

> both collections are in same db
>
> MongoDB server version: 3.6.9
>
> "mongoose": "^5.3.4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issue from this reference [Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup)

```
Users.aggregate([
     {
          $lookup: {
               from: "payments",
               // localField:"_id",
               // foreignField:"restaurant_id",
               let: {
                    id: "$_id" //localField
               },
               pipeline: [
                    {
                         $match: {
                              $expr:{
                                   $and:[
                                        {$eq: ["$status","Active"]},
                                        {
                                             $eq:[
                                                  "$$id", //localField variable it can be used only in $expr
                                                  "$restaurant_id" //foreignField 
                                             ]
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }


                         },
                    }
               ],
               as: "subscription"
          }
     }
])
```